# Restricting failed logins with a countdown timer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, authentication

I am currently practicing my coding by writing a simple login script containing a counter session variable that increases by 1 every time a login attempt fails. Once there are 3 failed logins, the login page will automatically direct the user to an "error" page with a timer counting down to when he can try logging in again.Once the timer hits 0, the counter session variable will be cleared(reset to 0) and the user can try logging in again.

I have written the login page with the session variable, but i'm currently stuck at the error page as i have no idea how to go about writing the timer.Im torn between using PHP(with TIMESTAMP) or Javascript/JQuery.

**Question:**

1.What are the advantages/disadvantages of both PHP and/or Javascript/JQuery

2.Im currently not tracking login attempts in my database, should i be doing so?

Thanks!
P.S: I'm currently using Uniform Server ,MYSQL

Comment: How are you reducing `$_SESSION['count']`? In my opinion, it'd be better to something like `if last login attempt > 10 mins ago, $_SESSION['count'] = 0` then `if $_SESSION['count'] >= 3 go to error page`

Comment: Use a PHP timer. I could easily turn off javascript in my browser and that could mess your timer up if it was written in js/jquery. It wouldn't hurt to store them in a database either

Comment: I think `session_start();` should be there always, why you checking if(!$_SESSION)

Comment: @PaulS. I'm planning to have a timer countdown from a specified time(e.g 5mins) then have $_SESSION['count']=0 once the timer finishes counting down.

Comment: @Ken, my point was to not have the "countdown", just check last attempted time

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks for your suggestion Paul, i implemented it and it's working. Would you like to leave your comment as an answer?

Comment: You could embed the time of the last log in attempt inside the SESSION variable and compare it with the time of the next log in attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `php` you could do something like the following (pseudocode)

```
# clear old counters
if last_login_attempt_time > 5_mins_ago
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0
# redirect if counter high
if $_SESSION['count'] >= 3
    send_client_to(error_page)
    die() # ensure code proceeds no further
# getting here means that attempting a log in is okay for this session
# attempt login
if login_unsuccessful
    $_SESSION['count'] += 1
    reload_this_page()
else
    continue_as_normal()
```

In your `error_page` (still `php`), if you want to indicate how long they need to wait

```
remain = 5_minutes + last_login_attempt_time - time_now
if remain > 0
    # tell client to wait for remain time
else
    # tell client they don't have to wait
```

If you want to make the countdown animated, you can pass the value of `remain` to some *JavaScript* on `error_page` and have it do a visual countdown *JavaScript*. This is just for visual effect and has no bearing on when the user can actually log in.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the clock I would use javascript, but with a php backend. The PHP would be used to store the actual time and the javascript could be used to count down the timer without a page refresh, then redirect once it hits zero.

For this you would need to add the times to the database. It doesn't hurt to add them anyway and can help with debugging or help with history later.

Comment: To add to your answer: The table containing the login *error locks* could also contain the user's IP Address.